# Interpretation of one word in difficult Kurrent handwriting

Tags: meaning-in-context, kurrent

I am currently transcribing a letter [image]from 1893 from Professor of Philosophy Marcus Jacob Monrad (1816-97) in Christiania (Oslo) to Professor Adolf Lasson (1832-1917) in Berlin.
However, I have problems with interpreting one single word, below marked with XXX. I would greatly appreciate a suggestion!:

*Ein anderes Werk von mir,

eine Aesthetik, hat mir einige

Ärgerniß veranlaßt.  Ich hatte

mit einem Leipziger Firma, C. E. M.

Pfeffer, Contract über eine deutsche

Ausgabe: ich sollte hier das Werk

übersetzen oder übersetzen lassen, und

so sollte dort ein deutscher Correc-

teur die nöthige sprachliche Durchsicht

vornehmen.  Das Druck war schon

begonnen, allein so zieht sich der Herr Verleger unsre

XXX Weise und ohne begreiflichen

Grund zurück, sucht Ausflüchte

und will nicht fortsetzen,

...*

Answer (score 4):

The preceding line does not actually end in "unsre", but rather in "uner-". The unidentified part (XXX) reads "warteter". This leaves us with: "so zieht sich der Verleger **unerwarteterweise** ... zurück".

Also note the following corrections: "Der Druck", not "Das" and "mit einer Leipziger Firma", not "einem".